# Как измерить растояние между игроками?

Tags: java, minecraft

Я пишу плагин в Minecraft, и застопорился на моменте измерения растояния между игроками.
Как мне сделать это?

Comment: Добавьте больше информации в вопрос, если будет код, это будет плюсом

Comment: А какие входные данные? Банальная теорема Пифагора не поможет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Информации мало. Зная координаты по трем осям обоих игроков это можно реализовать по формуле. Расстояние = √((xb — xa)<sup>2</sup>+(yb — ya)<sup>2</sup>+(zb — za)<sup>2</sup>), где ха-координаты первого игрока, а xb-координаты второго. Программная часть реализации сложностей вызвать не должна, тут чистая математика